# Unable to remove no-select attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I was trying to get the result image on the right as data to png format but it seems the resultant image is hosted somewhere else so data attribute I guess won't work anymore using the below code.

```
javascript: (function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("app-view").children[1];
    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(img);
})();
```

So I tweaked the code a bit to disable the no-select CSS feature on the right canvas but still it doesn't seem to work. At least it should have allowed one to right click on the right canvas image but still it isn't working. Here is the code.

```
javascript: (function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("app-view").children[1];
jQuery("canvas").remove(".noselect");
var imag = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(imag);
 })();
```

I am using it as a browser bookmark to test it in chrome for the above given canvas testing URL. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You code is equal to `jQuery("canvas.noselect").remove()`, you are looking for `jQuery("canvas").find('.noselect').remove();` .

Comment: @t.niese but still it won't allow to right click on the right hand side canvas image.Is there any workaround to be able to download the right hand side png image.

Comment: Sorry I am in a hurry and did not really read that it is  `canvas`. The Canvas is a 2D context that itself does not contain any elements. It just displays a rendered result of some drawing instructions. I only see an ascending element with  `.noselect`, so maybe you are looking for `jQuery("canvas").closest('.noselect')`?

Answer (score 0):

For very valid security reasons, canvas becomes "tainted" when you draw a cross-domain image onto it.

When tainted, the `canvas.toDataURL` command is disabled.

There are several workarounds:

- Delivering the image from the same server that is delivering your web page.
- Asking the administrator of the server hosting the image to allow anonymous access to that image.
- Delivering the image from a host that allows anonymous access to that image. There are several hosts willing to do this including Imagur (http://imgur.com/) and Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/) and probably others.

Comment: @Geniusknight Glad you got it sorted :-) Which workaround did you decide to use--just curious?